# Capturing live image and storing in encrypted form in database and decrypting on page load in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sql-server, image-capture

I am capturing a live image using JavaScript and storing that image in the database in encrypted form. Below is the code for storing image in database.

```
Session["imageName"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy hh-mm-ss"); 
Session["imagePath"] = string.Format("{0}.png", Session["imageName"].ToString());
Session["CapturedImage"] = ResolveUrl(Session["imagePath"].ToString());

private static byte[] ConvertHexToBytes(string hex)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(hex.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}

public static bool SaveCapturedImage(string data)
{
    string url = HttpContext.Current.Session["CapturedImage"].ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Session["CapturedImage"] = null;
    return true;
}

protected void btnUpload_Click1 (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
    {
        Session["hexString"] = Server.UrlEncode(reader.ReadToEnd());

        string filename = Session["imageName"].ToString();
        string contentType = Session["imagePath"].ToString();
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            byte[] bytes = ConvertHexToBytes(Session["hexString"].ToString());
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con2"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                string query = "insert into tblFiles values (@UId,@Name, @RelativeName, @ImageName, @ContentType, @Data, @uname)";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UId", txtId.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RelativeName", txtRName.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", filename);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", contentType);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", Session["uname"].ToString());
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    this.clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }          
}
```

How can I decrypted the image on page load at next page. I have tried many things but am not able to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't seem to have any encryption code.

Comment: As an FYI its highly recommended not to use `AddWithValue`. Instead create your parameters specifying the datatypes and sizes.

Comment: Perhaps the OP thinks of hexadecimal as a kind of encryption.

Comment: There's no encryption here, just corruption. The `ConvertToHexBytes()` code you've posted doesn't undo the operations performed by `Server.UrlEncode()`. Image streams tend to be binary data (with very few exceptions) so why aren't you just copying Request.InputStream to a MemoryStream and using its .ToArray() method to supply the @Data parameter with its value?

Comment: First of all Sorry for late reply. I am newbie. After many tries i was able to figure out that my encryption is wrong, that's why i posted it here for help. Will you guys guide me how to encrypted the image and save it, Some code will be very helpful.